# Is there a way that I can limit the number of request parameters in my method header in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

If I have a method that has like 10 request parameters and I may not always need all of them

```java
@GetMapping("/whatever")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendSomethingBack(@RequestParam String optionalRequestParam1, 
                                                @RequestParam String optionalRequestParam2,
                                                                   ... 
                                                @RequestParam String optionalRequestParam10)
```

So in this header I'd like something that is like

```java
@GetMapping("/whatever")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendSomethingBack(@RequestParam RequestParamBuilder requestParamBuilder)
```

and then it would just build an object for me with all valid parameters sent through filled out and the rest being null or something

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the meaning of these parameters? What relationship do they have to each other? How do you consume them?

Comment: They're Search parameters, used to filter search results based on filled-out fields and send them back to the user

Comment: If these are search parameters, better to you them in request body!

Comment: Or you can encode your all your search parameters to a single string! For example you can encode to `Base64`

Comment: You can consider either using a `@RequestParam Map` or Querydsl (which has integration with Spring MVC and Spring Data that allows you to use a predicate as a controller parameter and pass it to a repository).

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple parameters without defining their names by just using a `Map`:

```
@GetMapping("/whatever")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendSomethingBack(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> params) {
 log.info("Params: {}",  params.entrySet();
}
```

How to make the call:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/whatever?integer=45&string="some text"&boolean=true'
```

Output:

> Params: [integer=45, string="some text", boolean=true]

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the parameters to be passed into an object, you can use a POJO as you were but remove the @RequestParam notation:

```
@GetMapping("/whatever")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendSomethingBack(RequestParamBuilder requestParamBuilder)
```

Then create a class for `RequestParamBuilder`. You can mark the fields inside the POJO as `@NotNull` etc to handle validation and build out the object with only the params that were included in the request, but the POJO must be annotated with `@Valid` if you wish for spring to validate it this way:

```
@GetMapping("/whatever")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendSomethingBack(@Valid RequestParamBuilder requestParamBuilder)
```